# Are knowledge/trivia puzzles on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, close-reasons

Are knowledge/trivia puzzles on-topic? I'm talking about puzzles that are solved basically by knowing or looking up facts. I'm not talking about puzzles where this is just one element, or where the answer can be confirmed as fact but must be deduced or intuited first.

**Examples:**

[Start with an unlucky Friday](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/9779/4551)
[Denmark, Norway and Switzerland](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/9689/4551)
[Words that end with “-gry” aside from “angry” and “hungry”](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/9726/4551)
[Canada and USA geography puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/8838/4551)

([Related post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2821/4551))

Comment: The first one has a _lot_ of potential as a puzzle type, to my mind. It's along the same lines as a crossword. In that particular instance, the clues are too straightforward to be interesting to me, but it looks like it would be good fun if they were a bit more circumloquacious and cryptic. "Number of gables on Hawthorne's house", e.g., is a good start but still pretty easy.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the borderline between a *puzzle* and a (trivia) *question/quiz* is whether or not somebody has either

- to *combine* facts (in a non-obvious way) to arrive at the solution

or to

- have make some sort of *'progress'* through the whole thing. (i.e. knowing fact 1 allows you to understand and deduce to fact 2 etc.)

The second is a bit more "cross-word" style like - which, after all, is also just putting "facts" together. Still one *solves* it - one does not only *know* it.

Personally, to answer your actual question, I think *trivia questions* should not be on topic, but it is not always clear cut case to which category a posting belongs.

I agree with the comment of Josh Caswell that your first example, for me, is a puzzle. The others aren't really.

In general, I would start by rigorously *down voting* trivia-questions. Only if this is not enough to deter massive amounts of such questions should we go to the next level and vote-to-close.

Comment: Yes, yes. Trivia is something you _have_; a puzzle is something you _do_. An analogous dichotomy would be _scavenger_ hunts (go collect/visit this list of things/places) and _treasure_ hunts (figure out what to collect/where to go).

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I think a mathematician might argue that '**logic**' is the thing you *do* in solving a puzzle (or at least, *one* of the things you do). If we're too strict in assigning formal-logic-and-set-theory-and-number-theory-type-things to maths (or computer science) and disowning knowledge-type-things as too trivial, then it seems to me we're in danger of putting ourselves in a little small corner where there isn't any 'puzzling' left to do! :)

Comment: I agree with your criteria that fact-getting steps are fine if the result is combined into a whole, though I myself would have set a higher bar that the combining or progress takes ingenuity and cannot be step-by-step instruction-following.

Comment: @xnor I left it that "easy" to not exclude word-searches or cross-words, which are puzzles for sure. A puzzle is not *always* about logic - the very "puzzle" isn't. It's a *search, try & error* process of putting pieces together...

Answer (score -1):

**Let's allow them.**

Because:

- It saves us from having to debate/decide on the fuzzy line between facts, trivia, quizzes and puzzles.
- If we tag them (suggested tags: 'quiz'? 'trivia'?) then anyone who doesn't like them can easily set an ignore tag and not have to see them.
- There isn't an obviously-better place for them elsewhere on the SE network.

I've devised an example of the sliding scale / grey area between facts and puzzles.

We all agree that 'world capitals' is a knowledge/trivia kind of thing, right?

Below is a clueless crossword made out of world capital cities. Your challenge is to complete it by filling in the name of a current world capital city in each space.

[image: World capital cities - clueless crossword]

Puzzle, or trivia?

I think it's a subjective judgement which could go either way. I don't see one single set of obviously-right criteria for determining it.

And so by simply *allowing* 'knowledge'/'trivia'-type puzzles - but making sure they're clearly tagged so that anyone who doesn't like them can completely avoid seeing them - we can avoid wasting time debating the subjective-and-doesn't-really-matter-anyway question of where the dividing line between puzzles and knowledge is to be found.

Comment: That's clearly a puzzle, because it requires more than memorization and recall (or the external-to-brain version of that: looking it up in a book). The trivia version would be something like "list the top twenty world capitals by length of their name". Your third bullet point is no argument: there's no obviously-better place for [think-outside-the-box](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1254/) puzzles, [jokes](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2809/), or posts about constructing tinfoil hats, but that doesn't mean they fit on Puzzling.

Comment: I think your example of a crossword with words chosen from a list is definitely a puzzle, though I myself wouldn't enjoy looking through a long list. Even if you just gave all the words used, it would be a puzzle.

Comment: I'm the first upvoter of this answer :-)