# Is this question I asked on Math.SE better suited for Puzzling.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I had asked a question on Math SE, before I knew about Puzzling SE. Here's the link.

> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129004/create-the-most-stressful-tennis-game-ever

It does involve some maths, but it could be considered more of a puzzle. Please let me know where it is more appropriate; I'll delete the other version to avoid duplicates.

Comment: I am surprised that it didn't get a great answer on Math.SE! There are so many people there who are excellent with game theory, strategy, and these types of questions in general. I think it could go either place.

Comment: I think this question should be simplified at first. For one, having both player's skills randomly be between $0$ and $1$ will require integrating a (probably complicated) function over a square. Also, for even mildly complicated point systems, verifying the "90% of matches between 1000 and 1500 points" condition seems quite hard to check. Basically, this question seems pretty intractable as it stands, and narrowing down the search space would make it easier to get the ball rolling.

Comment: For me, the 90% between 1000 and 1500 condition was sufficiently arbitrary to turn what might otherwise be an interesting question into a probably-unanswerable mess.

Comment: @JLee Where should I delete it from?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code You decide. Either is fine. Maybe just leave it like you have it now, with the question there, and the link to it here, and whichever site it is answered on, then delete it from the other place. However, MikeEarnest hit the nail on the head.

Comment: If you're going to leave this question on puzzling.SE, I suggest stating the entire question here (in addition to the link).

Comment: @Julian and others, **Please tell me where to retain the Q and where to delete it.** I'm fine with it either way, I just want to know which is better.

Comment: In edge cases like this, the advice I've seen with other sites is: pick the site where you think you'll get the best response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Until a solution is posted, it's hard for us to say.**

The difference between a maths *puzzle* (suited for Puzzling.SE) and a maths *problem* (suited for Maths.SE) depends essentially on the way it needs to be solved - see [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2783/5373). The criteria for a maths *puzzle* listed in the accepted answer there are:

- Clever or elegant solution, often an "aha" moment.
- Unexpected problem statement.
- Unexpected or counterintuitive result.

That answer goes into a lot more detail about the distinction, but there's the essence of it.

Comment: Then I'll just leave it on Math SE. There may not be a good solution to it.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code There you go.