# Overuse of poor math questions, what can we do?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

So I've been noticing ... [lazy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80269/use-only-1-2-6-7-to-write-expressions-that-equal-31-32-33-34) [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80139/numerical-sequence-help) [puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79814/numerical-sequence). I thought it was just a fad, but clearly [not](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50804/make-12-with-1-5-19-10) .Now, I'm not trying to judge, but a lot of these questions are just in this weird gray zone where they're not very great puzzles, but aren't exactly *banned* in PSE.

I'm not proposing that mathematics tags should be removed or anything. I think it's a great tag.

[Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80169/1-0-1-0-1-0-1-0-1-0-1), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80050/using-only-1s-make-29-with-the-minimum-number-of-digits), and definitely [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79049/you-surely-dont-want-to-score-100-100) are just some of the numerous examples of a very creative and entertaining math puzzle.

The main question/complaint what are we (i.e. the community) be doing to improve the situation? [This](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic) was a great answer to the whole mathematical confusion, but then why is it still happening anyways? And branching off, should we add more to the tour regarding mathematics in general?

Comment: I mean, I *guess* you could always downvote, but there's gotta be a more effective way, especially for newcomers

Comment: I could also just be a big fat hater, and in that case, go ahead and dab on me, I guess

Comment: Funny, I was already [complaining about bad formation-of-numbers puzzles](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=22321657#22321657) in 2015.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If questions don't meet the criteria for Puzzling.SE, you should vote to close (or flag for closing if you don't have the rep to vote).

If questions *do* meet the criteria, but you feel they are not "good" questions (by some subjective measure of "good"), then downvote.  Many people are afraid to downvote, but this is exactly why downvotes are available.  They help to separate the wheat from the chaff.

If you notice that a particular *user* seems to be posting a lot of questions that you consider low-quality, you can always comment (politely) to them on one of their questions, or flag for a moderator if you feel it is a serious issue.