# Are questions that are just entertainment-based accepted here?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have seen many questions here that in my thought are just for entertainment, but they are receiving many up-votes. (questions on the first page of the site (Active ones) for example, are all being up-voted routinely.

Perhaps I am mistaking and I'm confusing the term entertainment.

But that's a question.

Well, I am new here and I asked a question that got down-voted; but I hope I can improve myself with good riddles :)

Comment: Ultimately, almost *all* puzzles on this site are for entertainment, i.e. people have fun setting them and solving them. Could you give links to a few examples and say why you find then problematical?  Please also give a link to the puzzle that you submitted so that we can comment on possible reasons for down-voting. Thank you and welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: @chasly, here's the link - https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100826/how-many-pigeons-are-in-the-flock - It appears it was closed as it was considered more of a math problem than a math puzzle.

Comment: One remark... Your comment that "I hope I can improve myself" is *exactly* the right attitude to have here on Puzzling :) It's the same reason so many of us are here - to keep being inspired by new puzzles, and to keep trying to push our own creations in ever more interesting directions. Keep this attitude at heart throughout your time on Puzzling and it will serve you very well. Keep trying and keep improving! :)

Comment: See our Meta question [Are math-textbook-style problems on topic?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2783/29192) for a lot more information on the difference between an off-topic math problem and a math puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

As @MacGyver88 has pointed out in a comment, your question was closed because "it was considered more of a math problem than a math puzzle".

Admittedly it may be difficult to draw a line. Before the invention of algebra, your question would indeed have been a puzzle. However because some basics of arithmetic, algebra, and geometry are assumed on this site, a math problem may be more a mechanical application of established rules than a puzzle that requires thought outside of the norm.

Don't be discouraged. I've had many questions closed on various parts of Stack Exchange. I still do occasionally but I'm learning and improving all the time.

Finally, it is well worth browsing through https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help