# Why was "Sum of digits of numbers" not well-received?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Sum of digits of numbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116257/sum-of-digits-of-numbers)
I recently posted this puzzle, I'm not sure why it is not well received. How can I make sure that this does not happen next time?

Comment: Just passing through quickly, so not enough time for a full answer, but if you haven't already you may want to read [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic) about maths puzzles vs maths problems. I imagine many people on viewing your post considered it a maths 'problem' rather than a maths 'puzzle' and voted accordingly.

Comment: My wordings might have made it look like a typical math problem. However it does have a very good solution.

Comment: i upvoted the question, and the accepted answer. Interesting in my opinion, but I'm only one person.